# ¿Algun consejo para conectar un cubo de SSAS con un pivot table de excel usando c#?

Tags: c#, excel, hoja-de-cálculo-tabla-dinámica

Estoy con un proyecto de desarrollo en el cual tengo que conectar por medio de C# en Visual Studio un cubo a una tabla pivot de Excel, en la cual pueda visualizar la información alojada en el cubo. Me preguntaba si alguno lo ha hecho o tiene idea de como para que me brinde ayuda. 
Lo que necesito hacer es muy similar a la conexion que se puede hacer con el cubo directamente dentro del documento de excel, solo que sea mediante codigo en c# y me genere el excel con los datos del cubo en pivot table.
Adjunto imagenes para dejar mas claro lo que necesito hacer. Solo puedo usar herramientas libres o que sean de microsoft.

[image: Pasos en excel]

Es hacer eso que se ve en la imagen, pero mediante codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar las api de office para crear el cubo desde codigo

[Creating a PivotTable Programmatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/07/25/creating-a-pivottable-programmatically/)

con la libreria COM `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, puedes crear el PivotCache

En el articulo conecta el pivotable a una base de datos Sql Server, pero en tu caso seria el mismo camino ya que es un origen de datos externo

[Creando Addin Excel C# para consultar Cubo](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/35db18c6-ec45-49f5-9785-55294a0b5c3d/creando-addin-excel-c-para-consultar-cubo?forum=ssases)

solo cambia como defines el connection string y el command

```
   string connection = @"OLEDB;Provider=MSOLAP.1; Location=xx;Connect Timeout=60; Initial Catalog=xx;Client Cache Size=25"; ;

   string command = "Nombrecubo";

   PivotCache pivotCache = wkbk.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlExternal, Type.Missing);

   pivotCache.Connection = connection;
   pivotCache.MaintainConnection = true;
   pivotCache.CommandType = XlCmdType.xlCmdCube
   pivotCache.CommandText = command;

   PivotTables pvtTables = (PivotTables)sheet.PivotTables(Type.Missing);

   PivotTable pvt = pvtTables.Add(pivotCache, sheet.Cells[8,3], "PivotTable1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```